# $n=6x+9y+20z$ when $n>43$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

A restaurant (KFX) serves chicken nuggets in 6, 9 or 20 packs. Show that you can buy $n$ nuggets if $n>43$.

I solved this problem in the following elementary way:
$$44=6+9+9+20,$$
$$45=9+9+9+9+9,$$
$$46=6+20+20,$$
$$47=9+9+9+20,$$
$$48=6+6+9+9+9+9,$$
$$49=9+20+20$$
But then, by adding $6$ packs to these, I can order any $n>49$ too.

What is the significance of 43 or 44 here? Can you solve this question in more theoretical way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cf. [McNugget numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#McNugget_numbers).

Comment: I think your method is close to optimal.  Perhaps one way to streamline it is to ask what the least representative of each congruence class $\pmod 6$ that you can write in this way.  $6,9,20$ already give you $0,3,2$.  We get $5$ out of $9+20$ and $2$ out of $18+20$.  So that just leaves $1$, and a simple search leads us to $9+40$.

Answer (score 1):

The generating function which calculates the number of ways for ordering nuggets is
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x^6)(1-x^9)(1-x^{20})}$$
Upto 300th order its series expansion at $x=0$:

[image]

43 is the largest power term whose coefficient is zero.
After 43 there is no other skipping.
$+2x^{44}$ term means there are 2 ways to order 44 nuggets: 6+9+9+20 and 6+6+6+6+20.